# Google BigQuery Standard SQL get weight summarize result by group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Original data

```
structure(list(Year = c(1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000), 
    Country = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b"), number = c(2, 
    3, 4, 5, 3, 6), result = c(2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

[image]

What I need is

Year Country weightresult

weightresult=result*(number/sum(number_year,country))
with weight result by number and the sum number is according to Year,Country group

the process result is

```
tructure(list(Year = c(1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000), 
    Country = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b"), number = c(2, 
    3, 4, 5, 3, 6), result = c(2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2), weight = c(2, 
    7, 7, 8, 8, 6), wre = c(2, 1.71428571428571, 2.85714285714286, 
    3.75, 0.75, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Finally need is

```
structure(list(Country = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), Year = c(1999, 
2000, 1999, 2000), wre = c(2, 4.5, 4.57142857142857, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

[image]

How to get the finally result in Bigquery Standard SQL

```
SELECT
Year,
Country,
(number/(SUM(number) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, Country))) * result AS wre,
Count(*),
FROM `table`
Where 
Year<=2020
GROUP BY Year,Country
ORDER BY Year,Country
```

And the error is

```
SELECT list expression references column number which is neither grouped nor aggregated at ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select
  year,
  country,
  sum(number * result) / sum(number) as weighted_result
from your_table
where year <= 2020
group by year,country
order by year,country
```

with output

[image]